# Page<T> Object throws NPE in foreach loop

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I have a test where a repository call returns a `Page<Entity>` object.

After this I'm iterating throught the elements in a foreach loop

```
    for (Entity entity : pageableObject) {
     //SOME CODE
    }
```

I'm always getting a `NullPointerException` at the forEach line.

I tried several things:

1. Create a dummy `PageImpl` with no elements
2. Mock the Pageable result.

Still I am getting an NPE. When I reach the forEach  loop, the pageableObject exists (as a real object, or as a mock depending on the solution 1 or 2)

What could be the problem here?

Comment: Have you debugged and checked what might be `null`? If you get the NPE at exactly `for (Entity entity : pageableObject) {`, then only `pageableObject` can be `null`

Comment: forEach uses hasNext and next methods. You need to mock this. Put your test code, so that we can suggest better

Answer (score 1):

You need to use like:

for (Entity entity : pageableObject.getContent()) 
{

`enter code here`

}

Comment: It is working by just using the pageableObject, just in the tests there is a NPE.

Comment: Ok, Then Can you debug it has elements or not? pageableObject.getTotalElements(), it should prints no of elements in peageableObject, if it has records then you should check what fields you are using inside loop(that field can be null).